# BER calculation in DS-UWB system

Tags: convolution, bpsk, matched-filter

I need to calculate BER (bit error rate) for a system using spreading spectrum DS over ultra wideband (UWB). Modulation is bpsk. The spreading sequence lengths are not equal for all users. Receiver is matched filter. I know the equations of DS-UWB transmission signal and template signal which I should use at receiver to extract the user's data. I know that I should use convolution between the received signal (transmitted + AWGN noise) and template signal. My problem is, how to calculate the result of that convolution? is it integration or multiplication?
thanks in advance

Comment: It's not so clear what you're asking. Convolution is...convolution. It involves multiplicaton and integration.

Comment: @Deve thanks for response. Can you tell me some reference where I can find details how mathematically the convolution output is calculated for ds-uwb?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't. What makes the convolution in DS-UWB different from a conventional convolution?

Comment: @Deve Actually this is my problem, I don't know how to calculate convolution between two sequences with different lengths.

Answer (score 1):

Assume two discrete-time sequences: $x$ (length $L_\mathrm{x}$) and $y$ (length $L_\mathrm{y}$). Furthermore, $L_\mathrm{x} \geq L_\mathrm{y}$. To calculate the discrete-time (linear) convolution of $x$ and $y$, first pad $y$ with $L_\mathrm{x} - L_\mathrm{y}$ zeros, i.e.
$$
y'(n) =
  \begin{cases}
    y & 0 \leq n < L_\mathrm{y}\\
    0 & L_\mathrm{y} < n \leq L_\mathrm{x} - 1
  \end{cases}
$$
Then calculate the convolution of $y'$ and $x$ as described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Discrete_convolution), for example.

Comment: The zero-padding is not required. It will just increase the amount of multiplications and since most of them will have one factor of zero, nothing is gained.